# Is Deno Currently usable as is? Version (0.2.1)

Tags: typescript, deno

I had a project spinned up in NodeJs, but I found out that I had to write a lot of boilerplate to get some functionality.

The system I was designing was supposed to run user code at times, and I had to look for various workarounds for functionailty that yet wasn't there in NodeJs(security), (supported natively).

Then along came Deno. I like it's approach on security first and typescript support (out of the box). Practically, it wipes out lots of the boilerplate code that I had on NodeJs.

My question is, can I use it as is currently safely (most probably I won't be using most of its core API's)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Deno is still very early in the development process and might involve a lot of breaking changes in the future (e.g. module system, timers, etc.).

Continue use Node in production, at least for now. However, early adopters of Deno are also highly welcomed (would like to know about feedbacks!)